# Old Toshiba laptop asks for (non-existent) HDD password

Tags: hard-disk, password, laptop, toshiba

I'm trying to wake up my old Toshiba Satellite 1410-604 laptop (bought in 2003) cause I want to use my old 35mm negative and slide film scanner which only runs on XP. Unfortunately, when I start the laptop it asks me for a "HDD password" which I'm fairly certain it never did before. I've thrown every root and admin password at it that I remember ever having used but with no success. Has anyone succesfully dealt with a similar problem? All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: sounds like the hard drive has password protection enabled ... try it on another computer ... the password prompt will most likely follow the drive

Comment: What does this have to do with Unix or Linux?

Comment: Good point: forgot to mention that it has a dual boot installed (though it's been dormant so long that I don't remember if the last distro was Crunchbang or Mint). I was hoping that someone here knew some nifty trick.